# graph performance monitor windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, performance-counters

We are using Munin to get graphs of our servers.  (such as CPU load, I/O, available disk space, etc. )
Munin gives us last 24h, last 7 days, last month and last year.

The good thing with Munin is that it supports all kinds of clients, such as Windows, Linux and switches because it can monitor over SNMP.

However, we have a problem with the Munin client for Windows. Since we upgraded to Windows Server 2008 R2 it won't show graphs for some performance counters.

What options are there out there? Both free and commercial.

Answer (score 1):

[PA Server Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/servermonitor) is what I use, though it's definitely stronger on the Windows side.

Answer (score 1):

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) has agent for Linux/BSD/Solaris/AIX/Windows, Zabbix is opensource monitoring solution

Answer (score 1):

I am using nagios. It is a good free monitoring software. It has a plugin to check Windows machines. Nagios grapher can be used to graph your performance data. However, i donst recommend to mix multiple monitoring programs at least for ease of use and management

Answer (score 0):

[Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) is a tool that stores numeric time-series data, and renders graphs of this data on-demand. This data is sent to the graphite server for storage, and can come from any arbitrary source. (It does not poll or read data; it receives it.)